# Preg_match symbols using?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In code

```
<div class="count">#3</div><div class="count">#4</div><div class="count">#5</div>
```

The numbers are different every time how can I see them who they are and to sum I tested with

```
$b = explode('</div><div class="count">', $cnt);
for($i=1;$i<sizeof($b);$i++)
    preg_match("/([0-9]+)/", $b[$i], $m);
```

but just see what the numbers but do not sum :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Regular Expressions even:

```
echo array_sum(str_split(filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)));
```

Outputs

```
12
```